# Image grid with various sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm building an imagegrid containing of 7x3 blocks, but one block need to fill out 2x2. I'd like to use a list since it have to be responsive (the 2x2 should pop out below on mobile). And I try to avoid javascript. But I cant make it work - any ideas ?

big grid:

```
img  img  img  img  img  img  img
img  img  img  img  blck....  img
img  img  img  img  blck....  img
```

mobile grid:

```
img  img  img  img
img  img  img  img  
img  img  img  img  
img  img  img  img  
blck..............
blck..............
```

Comment: use Bootstrap or any other grid system. Still, THIS specific layout will be cumbersome, but you'll save lots of time and headaches

Comment: and how would I "pop out" the blck-element ? clear:both in a mediaquery ?

Comment: it depends on how you build it. That last column with 1 img is problematic, but in Bootstrap you can define how many columns an element takes at different sizes, even without using media queries (although you may need adjustments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a friend at the office found a nice solution

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.images {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    width: 14.285714286%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
.group {
    max-width: 42.857142857%;
    float: left;
}
.group img {
    width: 33.333333333%;
}
.teaser {
    width: 28.571428571%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 28.571428571%;
    position: relative;
}
.teaser div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    img {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .group {
        max-width: 75%;
    }
    .group img {
        width: 33.333333333%;
    }
    .teaser {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        float: none;
        margin-top: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="images">
        <div class="group">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/EBE824/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/CECAA4/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/62C6A0/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/F8F07E/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/0F8B4B/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/EFB92B/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/63D1D2/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/F5C851/fff" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/42BFC0/fff" alt="" />
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/C44D58/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/FF6B6B/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/C7F464/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/4ECDC4/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="teaser">
            <div>follow me now</div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/556270/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/542437/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/53777A/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/C02942/fff" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```